# OpenXML SDK - Break external links in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

Is it possible using OpenXML to break links to external spreadsheets and convert formulas linked to them to values similar to how this works with the MS Office interop libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with "similar to how this works with the interop libraries", the simple answer is yes. Those links are all reflected in the Open XML markup, which you can change using the open-source Open XML SDK (see https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK). Thus, while the Open XML SDK-provided classes and APIs are certainly different from the Microsoft Office interop library-provided classes and APIs, the outcome or effect is the same.

Mind you the Open XML SDK provides you with very low-level access to the Open XML markup, so this is a very steep learning curve for somebody without prior experience with Open XML or the Open XML SDK.

To see how this can be done with the Open XML SDK, I recommend you download the [Open XML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (but use the latest [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) for any development). Should you have two versions of the same workbook, i.e., one with external links and one with those links removed, the Productivity Tool allows you to compare those documents and shows the differences in the Open XML markup and the C# code required to remove the Open XML markup, using the Open XML SDK.